# How do I push git commits in different Django directories to GitHub without having to keep doing pull merges?

Tags: django, git, github, git-merge

I am pushing one set of commits to GitHub from my Django app directory and another set of commits from my templates directory. Because each is a different directory, I had to set up a git remote in each one so that it knows to push to GitHub.

**Here's the problem:** Each set of commits has its own "master" branch that isn't aware of the other. First, I push the commits from the Django app directory's master branch to GitHub's master branch and that works fine. But then, if I push the set of commits from the template directory's master branch to the same GitHub master branch, I get an error saying that I need to do a merge before I can push. The push goes through after I do the merge, but it's annoying to have to keep merging the GitHub master to the different master branches of my different Django directories.

**My question is:** is it possible to set one master branch for all the different django directories I need to work with so that i can just do one push for files in all my directories? It seems that I need to initialize a .git file for each directory I want to work with which consequently gives each directory its own master branch.

Answer (score 0):

That is very strange. I use a single master branch for django projects that are hosted remotely on github.

You need to make a clone of the local repo in the topmost directory to have a single remote master branch.

For example, my project name is: BigCoolApp

If you do: cd /user/BigCoolApp

You should find a .git folder in there. It will be among all the other folders. If done correctly, you will now have a single master branch for your Django project.

Comment: Ok, say I have a folder in BigCoolApp with a file in it: BigCoolApp/directory/file.html and I edit file.html and want to add it to BigCoolApp's master branch staging index for commit, what's the best way? "git add BigCoolApp/directory/file.html" doesn't do it. Basically, how do you add changes in sub directories to the master branch of the top most Django directory where the local repo is located?

Comment: That is strange. when you do "git status" does it show that file.html has been changed? What I normally do is run: "git add ." and it adds all files to be committed (that have been changed).